# Calculate frequency in R studio without base::table() function

Tags: r, frequency

I am new using R, and I was doing some exercises. In particular, I was wondering if there is any way to calculate the absolute frequency of an X, but without using the function `table(x)`.

In other words, I want to get the same output given by `table(X)`, but without using this function. Is it possible?

Comment: `summary()`, `dplyr::count()`, for `data.table` `dt[, .N ,by = group]` all of those will provide similar outputs as `table()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of computing frequency (see, for example, comments) if the most immediate method, namely using the `table` function, must, for some reason, be avoided. One alternative way is by defining a `for` loop:

**Sample data**:

```
set.seed(123)
dt <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace = T)
```

To compute the frequencies you would first set up an empty vector to fill in the results of the `for` loop:

```
f <- c()
```

and then run the `for` loop itself, namely by looping over the unique elements in `dt` and `sum`ming them up, index by index:

```
for(i in unique(dt)){
  f[i] <- sum(dt== i)
}
```

This way you obtain this frequency list:

```
f
 B  D  C  E  A 
20 22 21 18 19
```

Comment: this is a good answer, but `u <- unique(dt); f <- setNames(integer(length(u)), u)` might be a better initialization

Answer (score 0):

One way to create frequency tables without `base::table()` is to use `tables::tabular()`. Here is an example where we create tables for a couple of discrete variables from the `mtcars` data frame. This approach has the benefit that it provides percentages in addition to frequencies.

```
library(tables)
tabular((Factor(am) + Factor(carb))~(n=1 + Percent("col")),data = mtcars)
```

...and the output:

```
       n          
        All Percent
 am   0 19  59.375 
      1 13  40.625 
 carb 1  7  21.875 
      2 10  31.250 
      3  3   9.375 
      4 10  31.250 
      6  1   3.125 
      8  1   3.125 
>
```

Another way is to use `dyplr` and `tidyr`. We'll pivot the `mtcars` data to narrow format, and calculate frequencies for three categorical variables:  `cyl`, `carb`, and `am`.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>% mutate(model = rownames(.)) %>% 
     group_by(model) %>% select(model,cyl,carb,am) %>% 
     pivot_longer(.,-model,names_to = "variable",values_to = "value") %>% 
     mutate(count = 1) %>% group_by(variable,value) %>%
     summarise(freq = sum(count))
```

...and the output:

```
   variable value  freq
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 am           0    19
 2 am           1    13
 3 carb         1     7
 4 carb         2    10
 5 carb         3     3
 6 carb         4    10
 7 carb         6     1
 8 carb         8     1
 9 cyl          4    11
10 cyl          6     7
11 cyl          8    14
```